# python, psutil, and steal time on ubuntu VM

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I would like to track steal time for my VM's in graphite.  I use psutils to send data to graphite.  How do I get steal time from python?  Is there a way to use psutils?  I am running ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but wth is "stealing time from a vm"?

Comment: I note sometimes that I get a steal greater than 0 using.  I am not a expert in this manner but that is another VM taking resources.  So..if on ec2 e.g. and there are two VM's on a single physical host, and one happens to be very compute intensive  I will want to boot more machines to offset the loss of power

Comment: Does this answer have you use python?  What if there is a canned way to get steal time into graphite?

Comment: I prefer python.  I have a process on all nodes that gets system state every 10 seconds using python and psutil and ships off to graphite. Even a shell command that I can run from python will be good.